# Recibir valor desde la vista al controlador

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, post

tengo un controlador que se encarga de hacer un `Login` que esto funciona bien, la cosa es que luego de hacer el `login` quiero recibir ese valor en el `ActionResult` pero siempre me trae `null`. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Este es la parte que se encarga del `Login`:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        try
        {
            ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
            var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);
            var existencia = sql.usuarioOCobrador(uname, psw);

            if (existencia[0].usuario == "USUARIO")
            {
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                var pruebaUsuario = sql.datos(uname);

                if (pruebaUsuario[0].clave == caracteres)
                {
                    sql.updateConectado(uname, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home", usuario);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Contra = "Contraseña incorrecta.";
                }
            }
            else if (existencia[0].usuario == "COBRADOR")
            {
                sql.updateConectado(uname, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Cuotas", "Home", usuario);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Usu = "Usuario incorrecto o usted no tiene los permisos para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con el área pertinente o el Departamento de Sistemas.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Y esta es su vista:

```
        <form class="modal-content animate" onsubmit="return control()" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Cerrar">&times;</span>
                <img src="~/Images/00.png" alt="Logo" class="avatar"/>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Usuario:</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Ingrese usuario..." name="uname" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"/>

                <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña:</b></label>
                <input type="password" id="psw" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña..." name="psw" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)"/>

                <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Ahora, como se ve uso: `@Url.Action("Login", "Home")` para llamar a mi otro `ActionResult`:

```
    public ActionResult Cuotas()
    {
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        string uname = Request.Params["uname"];
        var usuario = sql.datosCob(uname);
        if (usuario[0].conectado == false)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Cuotas");
        }
    }
```

Pero, uname es siempre null, ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que me ayudaron a encontrar para mi problema, fue la siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
{
    try
    {
        //Aquí seteo el valor obtenido desde el input en la vista
        Session["uname"] = uname;
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
```

Y aquí es donde lo aplico:

```
    public ActionResult Cuotas()
    {
        ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
        string uname = string.Empty;
        //Get your ViewData variables here
        if (Session["uname"] != null)
        {
            uname = Convert.ToString(Session["uname"]);
        }
```